# TAB completion not working for mounted partition

Tags: bash, ubuntu, mount, autocomplete, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm used to mount a Windows partition (G) into my Windows Subsystem for Linux (running Ubuntu 20.04) by giving the following commands:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/g
sudo mount -t drvfs G: /mnt/g
```

Unfortunately, writing in a shell, TAB completion of directories or files for such partition does not work (even if it works well for all the rest).

As stated in the comments below:

- the E partition seems to be mounted correctly, since `ls /mnt/g` shows all the directories and files within it
- it makes no difference launching WSL with `wsl ~ -e bash --noprofile --norc`

How could I solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you mount an `ext4` pertition, for example (try with a mounted file system image), completion works? And the windows partition is NTFS or what?

Comment: just to make sure - in the same shell does the TAB completion work for your home directory?

Comment: @Philippos The Windows partition is an NTFS. Honestly, I don't have a "system image" to test the TAB completion

Comment: @Andra yes, it works fine

Comment: I meant "file system image". You can just create and mount one: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/image count=200 && mkfs.ext4 /tmp/image && mkdir /tmp/mnt && mount /tmp/image /tmp/mnt && touch /tmp/mnt/foo` then try `ls /tmp/mnt/f` and hit TAB.

Comment: @Philippos the first command tells me `200+0 records in
200+0 records out
102400 bytes (102 kB, 100 KiB) copied, 0.001685 s, 60.8 MB/s
mke2fs 1.46.3 (27-Jul-2021)
/tmp/image: Not enough space to build proposed filesystem while setting up superblock` However, mounting the NTFS partition and running `ls /mnt/g` gives all the directories and files of the partition

Comment: em, I think for ext 4 200MB is slightly too less. Try replacing `ext4` to `ext2`: `mkfs.ext4 /tmp/image`

Comment: @BiG_NoBoDy it gives me the same error. However, we know the output of `ls` for my NTFS partition

Comment: So tab completion works on `/mnt/c` but not `/mnt/g`, correct?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds TAB completion doesn't work for any Windows partition mounted on WSL (all these partition are NTFS)

Comment: @user9952796 Okay, I can tell you that Bash's tab-completion for Windows/NTFS drives works fine for me (although I typically use the Fish shell).  We need to figure out what's different about your configuration.  Try starting WSL with `wsl ~ -e bash --noprofile --norc` to see if that makes a difference.  If so, then it's something in a startup config.  If not, we'll keep looking ...

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I started WSL with the command you proposed, but nothing change